# Initial data in android database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have an application with database and content provider. I was following tutorials but despite that, I get errors and cannot get rid of them. Especially when I try to add initial (demo) data to the database. Here are the errors that I get and the code that I use.

**Errors**

- When I install the app (without demo data), I get the following info:

  > Skipped 96 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
  >   At least, the application runs.
- Whenever I try to add demo data, the app shows the same info at the beginning. When I come to the screen with the list of items read from the database, it crashes. Here is the log:

  ```
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{….ItemListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:204)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at ….MyContentProvider.insert(MyContentProvider.java:83)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:201)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:864)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at ….DatabaseHelper.addItem(DatabaseHelper.java:78)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at ….DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:61)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at ….MyContentProvider.query(MyContentProvider.java:68)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at ….DatabaseHelper.getAllItems(DatabaseHelper.java:89)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at ….Items.getAllItems(Items.java:27)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at ….ItemListFragment.onCreate(ItemListFragment.java:26)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:796)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5017)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
  06-25 12:08:54.358: E/AndroidRuntime(4971):     ... 11 more
  ```

**Code**

I have a list activity with quite standard list adapter which I don't post, as I find it irrelevant.

The `Items` class requests the items from the database.

```
public class Items {

public static ArrayList<Item> getAllItems() {
    return new DatabaseHelper().getAllItems();
}
…
}
```

The database helper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private ContentResolver contentResolver;
…

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
}

public DatabaseHelper() {
    this(MyApplication.getContext());
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_ITEMS);
    //addItem(Items.getDemoItem());
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_TABLE_ITEMS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addItem(Item item)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(…);
    contentResolver.insert(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
}

public ArrayList<Item> getAllItems() 
{
    ...
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, 
            projection, null, null, null);

    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    while (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        …
        items.add(item);
    }

    cursor.close();
    return items;
}
}
```

Here is the content provider that I am using:

```
public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

// Variables used for content URI
private static final String AUTHORITY = MyContentProvider.class.getCanonicalName();
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_ITEMS);
private static final int SINGLE_ITEM = 1;
private static final int ALL_ITEMS = 2;
private static final UriMatcher URI_MATCHER;

static 
{
    URI_MATCHER = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    URI_MATCHER.addURI(AUTHORITY, DatabaseHelper.TABLE_ITEMS, ALL_ITEMS);
    URI_MATCHER.addURI(AUTHORITY, DatabaseHelper.TABLE_ITEMS + "/#", SINGLE_ITEM);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() 
{
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, 
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) 
{   
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_ITEMS);

    switch (URI_MATCHER.match(uri)) {
        case ALL_ITEMS:
            break;
        case SINGLE_ITEM:
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(DatabaseHelper.ITEM_ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(), projection, selection, 
            selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri); 
    return cursor;
 }

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) 
{
    switch (URI_MATCHER.match(uri)) {
        case ALL_ITEMS:
            long id = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase()
                    .insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_ITEMS, null, values);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            return Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
    }
}
}
```

Could someone find the error(s)? I understand that adding data to the database causes it to be called recursively but I don't really know how to avoid this. And why do I have so many things on the main thread? As I can't load my screen without the data, it doesn't really make sense to use an asynchronous task for reading the database. And I have no idea how to initialize the content provider in another thread.

Comment: Problem I see is you are opening the database connection multiple times in different classes..so you are getting those types of errors.

1. For first one `Application doing toomuch work` don't run the database operations on main thread instead use `Async task` this will reduce load on main thread.

2. For rest of database operations use `Singleton` class. So that there will be only one object created.

Comment: I open the database only in the content provider class. The `ContentResolver` should care about the connections. But, of course, not for the recursive ones... And the problem on the main thread comes when I install the application. At that point of time, I don't do requests to the database.

Comment: I couldn't find out how to remove the recursion, so I removed the content provider. At least for now, I would be really happy if someone proposes a real solution of the problem. In respect to the skipped frames, this still appears from time to time but as the frames are not that many, I suppose it is due to the emulator.

Comment: I am sorry that I am unable to provide you the solution for content provider.. but approach I used to follow is to create a `database class` that creates the database and for connection I use `singleton` in database class.. Now I used to create individual class for tables `creation` and `insertion` and will call that in database class and finally I will call the database in main activity.. This worked for me.. If you wish gove it a try.. Coming to emulator I would suggest you to use `GenyMotion` which is very fast compared to android emulator